# Computer slows down when I plug in a USB 3 flash drive

Tags: 16.04, usb, usb-drive

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS fresh install, on a Gigabyte GA-F2A88X-D3H Rev 3 motherboard.

- Keyboard and mouse work fine when I have nothing in my USB 3 hub.
- If I connect USB 2 flash drives in the hub, no problems.
- If I connect a USB 3 flash or hard drive, all USB's become unresponsive, and cannot use Keyboard or mouse until I unplug it.

Where do I start to find the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Do not know if this model is similar enough, but have seen other Gigabyte boards needing IOMMU in UEFI changes and the boot parameter `iommu=soft` [SOLVED] GA-970A-DS3P revision 1 no usb 3.0
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2188370

Comment: That was it. You want to put that as an answer and I will credit it to you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not know if this model is similar enough, but have seen other Gigabyte boards needing IOMMU in UEFI changes and the boot parameter iommu=soft

GIGABYTE GA-970A-DS3 motherboard not working with 64 bit kernel - IOMMU GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="iommu=soft"

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2188370

Similar issues:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2111223&page=5

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2292025

Answer (score 2):

Does your USB flash drive have an activity LED? Is it flashing rapidly when you plug it in? If you do not have an activity LED, run

```
sudo apt-get install dstat
```

then run

```
dstat
```

Look at your CPU and Disk usage, and see what is using up your resources.

Also keep in mind that dstat will run until you tell it to stop, so remember to CTRL-Z when you're done.

Dstat can still be helpful even if you DO have an LED to look at because it will also display your CPU, Network, and other resources. Which may be helpful in solving your issue.

Comment: I ran Dstat. So, it's not the CPU or anything going crazy, I guess it is that my USB mouse and keyboard aren't happy when I plug it in as my mouse tracking is all over the place and choppy and there is a long delay/dropped characters with my keyboard. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have same motherboard. People [suggested](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/535495-No-reboot-or-poweroff-after-upgrade-to-5-0-x-kernel?p=2899394#post2899394) to do other thing:

### In the BIOS:

- Enable XHCI Handoff
- Disable EHCI Handoff
- Enable IOMMU

### Kernel command line additions:

`amd_iommu=on iommu=pt`

Works fine for me.